# fancyBox 2 official DEMO throwing error when loaded on local machine when attempting to test Vimeo & YouTube playback

Tags: jquery, html, video, fancybox

I am writing plain HTML & CSS and loading the file directly in the browser from my local hard drive.

FancyBox 2 is loading the lightbox effect, so I know the script is working, but I am receving the following error message when attempting to play a video:

```
"This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: file://player.vimeo.com/video/25634903?hd=1&autoplay=1&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&color=&fullscreen=1
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found."
```

Notice that the script is attempting to load the video from `file://` even though the HREF URL I specified is `HTTP://vimeo/25634903`

I then loaded the demo file in my browser, locally, attempted to play the youtube and vimeo video examples and I received the same error. The demo does load images properly, but not videos.

Is there something I can tweak in the fancBox js file that will allow me to use this locally? Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE 1: some text was scraped out when I posted this: "...even though the HREF URL I specified was http:// etcetcetc"

I just tested on MAC & Windows, not that I expected anything different and I see the same behaviors.

Comment: UPDATE 2: I just copied my personal work and the official demo to an actual web server and tested the fancyBox video playback and everything worked perfectly. Therefore, there clearly seems to be a bug / oversight in the fancyBox code that prevents the fancbox-media / video playback from working when loaded on a local machine.

Comment: the URL http://vimeo.com/25634903 return a 404 Page not found ... are you sure you are passing the right video reference?

Comment: I replaced the url for the vimeo video that is in the demo index.html with a new one: vimeo.com/42803796 (with the http://) then loaded it in the browser from my hard drive, same issue. Now that you pointed this out, I see that the video referenced in the demo was deleted from vimeo, but the issue remains. I don't think fancyBox ever got past the file:// reference.

Comment: You can download the demo here: fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license - load the index.html file, replace the vimeo video URL with a working one and then load index.html in your browser. The video in the fancybox feature will NOT work, but the images will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply open a html file in the browser it load the file with `file://` scheme. Most good scripts are designed to use protocol relative URLs, by giving urls as `//<url>`. For eg,   if the page is loaded as `https` scheme, it automatically loads `https://<url>`.

That is one of the reasons why it is always a good idea to test java script/html on a real web server instead of opening the file directly.

Also, some browsers with no-script or similar plugins disable certain js functionality for scripts loaded as `file://`

Comment: Right, the code works on a web server, which is great, but I think the problem might be what you mentioned: that the script is not using a relative URL scheme for the videos? The images work fine loaded locally. My goal is to be able to demo this in front of a client without having to rely on a web server.

Comment: @ChevasBalloun the images work fine locally because they are stored locally (included in the demo file) but the video is referenced using `//`. As mentioned by @Xero, in a webserver the `http://` will be added while locally `file://` will be used instead. I vote this as the correct answer.

Comment: @JFK Okay, I get it now. Thank you for your commentary on Xero 's answer and I can see now that it makes sense. I think I got tripped up in how he worded it. Once a script identifies a scheme (whether http or file), it's going to look for all the content with that scheme. Since it identified that the files were local, it used file:// ...everywhere... Cool, I learned something new today. Thank you for your patience with me. This is a misidentified "error".